# Auto populate a column respect to row

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google sheets apps script, but I do not know what the best path is to achieve this.
How can I populate column D with whatever is in column A highlight area respectively for the all items?

This is the result that is desired.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNVWR.png)

Thank you in advance,
Abe

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this in `Cell_D2` of your test setup:*

```js
=scan(,A2:index(A:A,xmatch("end",A:A)),lambda(a,c,ifs(c<>"",,offset(c,-1,)<>"",offset(c,-1,),1,a)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. This seems to work for this situation but how can this be applied to a situation where the rows in-between the items are less or more.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Hmm will this work ?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17aWCvsILZidOAP2WznNl4l17GQxXQRMpgQcSIqG8GdM/edit#gid=949043960

Comment: I've added the formula in Column_G. only change done to the above formula is altering  `A2:` to `A3:` (since data is starting from row_3 in the test sheet you shared)

Comment: It seems when I add text to the blank space on column_A it breaks the code.

Comment: yeah the formula is not written/intended for a scenario like that...

Comment: How would i go by doing that?

Comment: any update on how to approach this?

Comment: With your piece of formula I figured it out. I appricate it. Thank you